# mysql select based on a SUM

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do a mysql query but Im not sure how to go about it.

I want to select rows that are greater than the php value of `$x`, by adding 2 of the table fields together (after dividing them).

The pseudo code:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field_a/50 + field_b/20)  > $x
```

The `$x` is a php value, its just the sum i need.

Anyone have tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much the pseudo-code you wrote:

```
$x = 100; // example
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($x); // "securing" the value.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field_a/50 + field_b/20)  > '$x'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Using parameters is more elegant, but you got the idea. This way you can mess the SQL query if `$x` is empty or have any not expected value. I handled this issue escaping the value using `mysql_real_escape_string` before using it in the query.

**EDIT**

The same example using MySQLi:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field_a/50 + field_b/20) > ?");

// "i' is a format string, each "i" means integer
$stmt->bind_param("i", $x); // use "d" instead of "i" for double

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
```

Comment: Avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider using
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for starting.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much exactly how you'd go about it. Other than making sure $x is properly numeric before building the query string, you've got it.

One minor suggestion - if you do this sort of query frequently, you might want to consider cacheing the value of the `field_a/field_b` stuff in a separate field. It's a slight denormalization, but it would allow this field to be indexed and probably improve performance. Right now you're doing a where on a derived/calculated value, which makes it impossible to use indexes.